# Restrict S3 objects URL only to logged in users on a website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My website has some files hosted on AWS S3 buckets, but I need to restrict access to the s3 objects URL to only logged in users of the website. Something similar to how google drive works. which means that anyone trying to access the urls to any of the files on our S3 bucket needs to be logged into the website before he or she would be able to.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: May be you can start with restricting public access to the bucket. Next is to create temporary tokens for users which logs in and generate temporary urls of the objects which are valid for a specific duration...

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to restrict access to the S3 objects, don't make the objects public and don't use the public URLs shown on AWS S3 console.

S3 provides an option to generate pre-signed URLs to download S3 objects. So once your users log in to your website and when they request to download the S3 object, make a request to S3 to generate this pre-signed URL. Clicking on the pre-signed URL will download the object.

With pre-signed URLs, you can configure additional options like expiry time, so that these URLs are more secure.

You can find more info about pre-signed URLs and their implementation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html).

Comment: I already have this implementation, i did it using Cloudfront, am trying to replicate (although not exactly) the way Google drive works, before you can access any URL to its resource, depending on the permission ? you'll need to actually log into your gmail and access it if you are authorized.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to use AWS Cognito for log in/out functionality, you can assign IAM roles to logged in users.

This way when trying to access the s3 bucket, you can restrict access using IAM roles.

AWS Amplify would be a good fit for this use-case.